# Ajax div .slideDown to correct height

Tags: jquery, height

I'm having a little trouble having a div to adjust to the correct height, the first time you click a link.

The problem can be found at: [tomrawcliffe.com](http://www.tomrawcliffe.com)

As you can see, when you click on a portfolio link in the fist instance slideDown slides only 50px or so and then jumps once the rest of the content is loaded. Although in the second instance when you click a link it loads fine.

Any suggestions?

Here's the jQuery. And I'm working in Wordpress.

```
     $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $(".load_this").click(function(){
            var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#page_loading").show();
            $("#single-home container").slideUp("slow").load(post_link).slideDown("slow");
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call your slideDown after the content is loaded, like this

```
$("#single-home-container")
    .slideUp("slow")
    .load(
        post_link,
        {},
        function() {
            $(this).slideDown('slow');
        }
    );
```

Comment: I think I'm going to sound a little like a noob when saying this, but I can't get that to work? It just loads the page, rather than place it in the #single-home container

Comment: $("#single-home-container").slideUp("slow").load(post_link,{},function){$(this).slideDown("slow");}

Comment: My days! Can't believe I didn't see that! Thank you very much.